# How to convert an unsigned byte to a signed byte

Tags: java, type-conversion, byte, unsigned, signed

I am trying to convert unsigned bytes from a file to signed bytes in java. This is the current arrangement I have for reading unsigned bytes from a file in java:

```java
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (String string : fileKeyString) {
            output.write(Integer.valueOf(string).byteValue());
        }
        return output.toByteArray();
```

> Note: I have to use Java 8 and fileKeyString is a String Array that gets created when reading from a file. The variable string holds the unsigned byte. It outputs a byte array which is required.

How would I exactly convert this from an unsigned byte to signed bytes before it gets placed into output.write and evaluated by .byteValue()?

I dont have too much expereience with bytes so any help is appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: You could try something like: `if (byte >= 128) { byte -= 128; }`

Comment: try `(byte)Integer.valueOf(string)`

Comment: Which is the unsigned byte in your code? Does the `string` contain the unsigned byte in decimal form?

Comment: @Sweeper yes string holds the unsigned byte in decimal form. Sorry i should've specified that in the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! You just subtract by 256 if it exceeds by 128.

```
if (byte >= 128) { byte -= 256; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to misunderstand how computers work.

A byte is what it is. Just `01001100` on disk or in memory. What does `01001100` mean? Is that signed or unsigned? The byte doesn't know. Bytes just are 8 bits, that's it. That's all they ever are. It's things that interact with the byte that decide how one is to read it. Is that signed? The byte has no idea - the software (or the human eyeballs) that look at it decide whether it is or not.

Let's make it more interesting and work with the byte `10000000`.

What is that? The byte has no idea. Perhaps you have some software that reads this byte and shows the value of it on screen.

Depending on which software you use, you might see any of the following and they are all **equally correct**:

- 128 (interpretation: It's an unsigned byte, show it in decimal)
- -128 (interpretation: It's a 2s complement signed byte, show in decimal)
- 80 (interpretation: Show it in hexadecimal, unsigned)
- -80 (interpretation: Show in hex, signed)
- � (interpretation: It's a unicode character. The 128th item in the unicode table is 'control', and not really a character perse).
- -127 (interpretation: It's a 1s complement signed byte, show in decimal)
- Nothing appears on screen, instead, the dulcet tones of Unchained Melody blast out of the speaker (interpretation: It's an id of a song, and Unchained Melody's ID is bit sequence 10000000).

Given a file containing just 1 byte, with bitsequence 10000000 (which is just a sequence of bytes, no metadata), you have no idea which of the above interpretation is correct. In that sense they are ALL correct. I can make you a file which, if you name it 'foo.zip' and unzip it produces 1 file with the collected works of shakespeare in plain text inside. If you rename the .zip to .png, and open it, you see the mona lisa. Same bytes in either case - it's the app that reads them that causes those exact same bytes to mean something completely different.

The exact same principle (it's not the byte itself, it's the software or human eyeballs that decide what it means) applies in reverse as well: If I want to 'write' Unchained Melody to disk, it's the software that decides how to do it.

With that in mind, therefore:

> How would I exactly convert this from an unsigned byte to signed bytes before it gets placed into output.write and evaluated by .byteValue()?

That question makes no sense. If I have the number -128 and I want to write it to disk, presumably you just write the bit sequence 10000000 to disk and, yup, that doesn't mean anything unless the user of the computer opens that file again **with your app**. Or any other app that knows that it is to be interpreted as a signed 2's complement byte.

The code you have already writes 1 byte to disk whose bit sequence is 10000000; you're already doing it, your code is fine as is.

If you are opening it with something and that says 'this file contains +128', and you want that to say '-128' instead, there is nothing you can change in your file writing code. Instead, you need to find different software to open it, or configure that software differently.